# ¿Cómo corregir este error Broken pipe al usar sockets en python?

Tags: python, socket, server, semaphore

La idea de este código es que el server acepte clientes cuando la variable "access" es True. El problema es que cuando esta en False, no entra correctamente en el ultimo else. En vez de enviar el mensaje y cerrar la conexion adecuadamente, salta un error en el lado del cliente (`BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`). Como lo arreglo?

```
semaphore=threading.BoundedSemaphore(3)

lock=multiprocessing.Lock()

def handle_client(conn,addr):
    connected=True
    print(f"Nuevo cliente conectado. Direccion {addr}")
    
    id_con=uuid.uuid1().int
    id_con=id_con/1000000
    
    lock.acquire()
    consulta(id_con)
    lock.release()

    while connected:
        msg_length=conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length=int(msg_length)
            msg=conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg==DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                semaphore.release()
                print('Dijo que se va')
                connected=False
                break
            # imprimo en la consola del server
            print(f"Usuario {addr} dice {msg}")
            
            resultado=back.foto(msg,neuronas,pixeles_fotos=[])
            # imprimo en la consola del client
            conn.send(f"(SERVER MESSAGE). Usted dijo {msg}. El resultado es: {resultado}".encode(FORMAT))
    
    conn.close()    

def start_server():
    print("Servidor escuchando...")
    server.listen()
    
    while True:
        conn, addr=server.accept()
        access=semaphore.acquire(blocking=False)

        if access==True:
            thread=threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(conn,addr))
            thread.start()

        else:
            conn.send(f"(SERVER MESSAGE). Conexion rechazada por exceso de demanda".encode(FORMAT))
            conn.close()

p=multiprocessing.Process(target=start_server)
p.start()
p.join()
```